# Why is class(.SD) on a data.table showing "data.frame"?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

colnames() seems to be enumerating all columns per group as expected, but class() shows exactly two rows per group! And one of them is data.frame

```
> dt <- data.table("a"=1:3, "b"=1:3, "c"=1:3, "d"=1:3, "e"=1:3)

> dt[, class(.SD), by=a]
   x y z         V1
1: 1 1 1 data.table
2: 1 1 1 data.frame
3: 2 2 2 data.table
4: 2 2 2 data.frame
5: 3 3 3 data.table
6: 3 3 3 data.frame


> dt[, colnames(.SD), by=x]
    x y z V1
 1: 1 1 1  a
 2: 1 1 1  b
 3: 1 1 1  c
 4: 1 1 1  d
 5: 1 1 1  e
 6: 2 2 2  a
 7: 2 2 2  b
 8: 2 2 2  c
 9: 2 2 2  d
10: 2 2 2  e
11: 3 3 3  a
12: 3 3 3  b
13: 3 3 3  c
14: 3 3 3  d
15: 3 3 3  e
```

Comment: code is not reproducible: `data.table("a"=1:3, "b"=1:3, "c"=1:3, "d"=1:3, "e"=1:3)[, class(.SD), by=x]`

Comment: Apologies, it should have been by=a. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

`.SD` stands for column Subset of Data.table, thus it is also a data.table object. And because data.table is a data.frame `class(.SD)` returns a length 2 character vector for each group, making it a little bit confusing if you expect single row for each group.
To avoid such confusion you can just wrap results into another list, enforcing single row for each group.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x=1:3, y=1:3)
dt[, .(class = list(class(.SD))), by = x]
#   x                 class
#1: 1 data.table,data.frame
#2: 2 data.table,data.frame
#3: 3 data.table,data.frame
```

Answer (score 1):

Every data.table is a data.frame, and shows both applicable classes when asked:

```
> class(dt)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

This applies to `.SD`, too, because .SD is a data table by definition (.SD is a data.table containing the **S**ubset of x's **D**ata for each group)